# I need to set the "job info" for users in my Azure AD e.g. "department". The Set-AzADUser has no parameter for this. Is there another command?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory

I have created a script to 'bulk add' users from csv using the Import-Csv cmdlet. I created a loop to add a new Azure AD User from each row. The company has no existing AD we are creating one from scratch in the cloud.

My problem is, the only available parameters I see do not include setting attributes such as "job title" or "department" which could easily be added into the CSV.

Is there another way to accomplish setting these attributes that I can include in my loop?

Link to the code with MIT license: https://github.com/bustelyo/Az-AD-Bulk-User-Add

Comment: the MS docs site does NOT list any such cmdlet as `Set-AzADUser`. it does list `Update-AzADUser` but it doesn't seem to have any of the properties you mention.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey that's what I was afraid of. Manually updating each attribute.

Comment: Are you trying to update already added users or adding new users based on CSV? If you're adding new users, then `New-AzureADUser` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/new-azureaduser?view=azureadps-2.0 does support parameters for `-Department` and `-JobTitle`

Comment: Even `Set-AzureADUser` supports these parameters.. They are missing only in the newer Az module commands.. like `New-AzADUser` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/new-azaduser?view=azps-1.6.0 .. So you could potentially use Azure Active Directory Powershell 2.0 commands like `New-AzureADUser` to do this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

New commands [**`New-AzADUser`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/new-azaduser?view=azps-1.6.0) and [**`Update-AzADUser`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/update-azaduser?view=azps-1.6.0) available with **`Az PowerShell 1.6.0`** don't seem to have explicit parameters for `-Department` and `-JobTitle` that you're looking for.

**Alternatives** (to avoid manual updates as you mention)

- [**`New-AzureADUser`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/new-azureaduser?view=azureadps-2.0) and [**`Set-AzureADUser`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/set-azureaduser?view=azureadps-2.0) commands available with **`Azure Active Directory PowerShell 2.0`** and [**`AzureAD`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/?view=azureadps-2.0) module.

  Here is a [very detailed script](https://charbelnemnom.com/2018/03/how-to-create-bulk-users-in-azure-active-directory-with-powershell-azuread-powershell-aad/) which uses these commands and bulk imports new Users
- Azure AD Graph API:

  [Create a User](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/ad/graph/api/users-operations#create-a-user-work-or-school-account--) - You can call the REST API directly or use client SDK libraries.

  ```
  POST https://graph.windows.net/myorganization/users?api-version
  ```
- Microsoft Graph API:

  [Create User](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-post-users?view=graph-rest-1.0) - You can call the REST API directly or use client SDK Libraries.

  ```
   POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users
  ```